# shipping information was unable to be saved .Verify the input data and try again

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, shipping-address

I am using **magento 2.3.2.** While I am doing checkout and enter my mail id then immediately I am receiving this error.I am attaching the issue. Please let me know the exact issue I am facing.Initially I am doing checking with this **email id** only.But that time I never get this type of issue.[image]